# Perl regex one-liner hangs on tail -f, but not on tail

Tags: regex, perl, tail

I'm obviously missing here something in between how the perl loop works, tail -f and regex.

Setup:

```
@$ echo xab > a
```

Test:

```
@$ tail a | perl -pe 's/[^a]/*/g'    
a     

@$ tail -f a | perl -pe 's/[^a]/*/g'
```

... Nothing!!

Discussion:

maybe it's loop?
but this also hangs:

```
@$ tail -f a | perl -e 'while (<>){s/[^a]/*/g}continue{die "-p destination:$!\n" unless print $_;}'
```

it could be /g, because this works

```
@$ tail -f a | perl -pe 's/[^a]/*/'    
ab
```

it could be -pe, because this works

```
@$ tail -f a | perl -lpe 's/[^a]/*/g'    
a
```

it could be regex, because this works

```
@$ tail -f a | perl -pe 's/x|b/*/g'    
a
```

I'm lost. What's going on here?

Comment: but why am I not suffering in other cases?

Comment: not true. other cases return (almost) immediately, and on appending to file reflect the changes (almost) immediately. this one hangs forever. I suspect it's something about /g which is not printed correctly, but I have no idea why.

Comment: [Suffering from Buffering](https://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between those that "work" and those that don't is whether a LF was printed or not.

When their STDOUT is connected to a terminal, many programs will flush it on a LF or when the associated buffer becomes full. Perl follows this pattern, and those conditions haven't been met yet in the cases where you don't immediately see some output.

Adding the following will disable buffering on STDOUT:

```perl
BEGIN { $| = 1; }
```

Comment: I get your point in general case, and that explains why `perl -pe 's/[^a]/_/g'` doesn't work while `perl -pe 's/[^a]/\n/g;'` works, and why -lpe works. But that's not a full answer: `perl -pe 's/[^a]/_/'` works without LF printing, just probably because regex expects only one match which triggers the buffer flush (?). And the last regex `x|b` flushes even with /g option, probably because x|b can't match end of line (?).

Comment: `s/[^a]/_/` and `s/x|b/*/g` work because they don't remove/replace the LF.